# How to interpret a multi-particle wave equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, coulombs-law

Near the end of my introductory quantum mechanics lectures the lecturer introduced multi-particle states with distinguishable particles, notably product states

$$|\psi \rangle = |\psi^{(1)} \rangle ... |\psi^{(N)} \rangle$$

with upper indices running over N particles

As an example of an operator acting on several particles he gave the Coulomb potential (promoted to an operator through canonical quantisation)
$$V_{Coul}(\hat{\vec{x}}_{1}, \hat{\vec{x}}_{2}) = \dfrac{q_{1}q_{2}}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \times \dfrac{1}{|\hat{\vec{x}}_{1}-\hat{\vec{x}}_{2}|}  $$

where $\hat{\vec{x}}_{i}$ acts on particle i

He then introduced the following wavefunction which I have trouble interpreting
$$\psi(\vec{x}_{1},\vec{x}_{2}) =\langle \vec{x}_{1},\vec{x}_{2}|V_{Coul}(\hat{\vec{x}}_{1}, \hat{\vec{x}}_{2}) |\psi \rangle$$

Should I interpret this as $\int_{V_{2}}\int_{V_{1}} dx_{1}dx_{2}|\psi(\vec{x}_{1},\vec{x}_{2})|^{2}$ giving the probability of both finding particle 1 in V1 and particle 2 in V2 after immediate successive measurements, given that particles 1 and 2 interact via the Coulomb potential ?

This is my guess, since I am given that operators acting on different (distinguishable) particles commute, therefore making a statement about the measurements of both x1 and x2 doesn't seem to pose any obvious problems to me.

Comment: $V_1$ and $V_2$ refer to same physical space (being the whole "universe" mathematically) The only difference is you have to integrate over all space twice, once for each particle.

Comment: Would this not just give me 1 ? (Assuming states are normalised) What information is gained ?

Comment: Oh now I understand your confusion. The bra ket your teacher gave is the wave function, not the integral of it. While the position and momentum "basis vectors" are not well defined kets strictly speaking, they are well defined as bras i.e. $$\langle x | \psi \rangle = \psi(x)$$ The way you should interpret this is that the state vector is a large, abstract quantity (like a database) and its position space wave function is only one aspect (or coordinate) of it. This is because the earliest notion in a QM class, that quantum state $=$ wave function, is not correct

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me get more comfortable with understanding the state vector as a data base and its position space wave function being only one aspect of it that we "fetch" using the position bra. 
From what I understand, in the single particle case, the absolute value squared of this wave function can be integrated over a volume to give the probability of finding the particle in that volume. What I'm trying to get my head round is whether there is a similar interpretation for a multi-particle position space wave function, like the one my teacher gave.